# bundle install error with jRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, jruby

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/nikhil/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/bin/jruby -r ./siteconf20151019-18379-17l4c3t.rb extconf.rb
/home/nikhil/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:14: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /home/nikhil/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/native/include/ruby/ruby.h

extconf failed, uncaught signal 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/nikhil/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19@mbiprint/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/nikhil/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19@mbiprint/extensions/universal-java-1.6/1.9/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing binding_of_caller (0.7.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install binding_of_caller -v '0.7.2'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

Can anyone please solve this. I am getting this error while using jRuby as RVM. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`binding_of_caller` does not work with JRuby. See the [README](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller):

> Only works in MRI Ruby 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0, 2.1 and RBX (Rubinius)

and

> There is experimental support for jruby 1.7.x, but it only works in interpreted mode (i.e. use the option `-Djruby.compile.mode=OFF` or append `compile.mode=OFF` to your `.jrubyrc`)

Answer (score 0):

sudo gem install binding_of_caller -v '0.7.2' in terminal and hit enter and if it is not working then go in gemfile open it in notepad and  comment the lines (means put # sign) binding_of_caller

Comment: I have tried both. Still not lucky. Even I have not added this in my Gemfile but when I command for bundle install, it gives above listed error.